# java Standalone Client to remotely deploy war file to ibm liberty 20.0.0.x

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

How can java standalone client can be implemented for remotely deploying war file to ibm liberty 20.0.0.x?
No documentation found for standalone deployment script at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/cwlp_server_clusters.html
Any modifications should be done to war before deploy to ibm liberty?

Comment: You need to rewrite your question as it is not clear what you want to do. If you want to deploy app to Liberty, you need to put `war` file to `dropins` folder or to `spps` folder and configure it in `server.xml`. Check this [Deploying applications in Liberty](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_dep.html)

Comment: If you want to install app remotely, which I would strongly not recommend, you need to use MBeans, and FileTransfer. Check these: [Establishing a JMX MBean Liberty server connection](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_admin_serverconnection.html)  and [File Transfer](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/cwlp_file_transfer.html)

Comment: Hi Gas thanks for the suggestion, requirement is to deploy remotely. why it is not recommended to use MBeans and FileTransfer?

Comment: Liberty is a lightweight server, so the recommended approach is to build and deploy server with application as a package together. So you just unzip the package in your target env and build the whole stuff by your CI/CD tooling. When you need to upgrade app then you just replace whole package.

Comment: Hi Gas appreciate the suggestion, requirement is to build custom CI/CD so has to deploy war remotely. if copied the war explodes to expanded folder but when posted with rest to url IBMJMXConnectorREST/file/ , gets error [ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\server1\dropins\testapp1.war.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0021E: The server is not configured to handle the resource at location C:\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\server1\dropins\testapp1.war.

Comment: Probably archive is incorrectly transferred. Check this page - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.swagger.doc/jmx_swagger.json . Make sure that you are using POST and set the Content-Type header to ‘applicaton/zip’

Comment: it got resolved when postman  posted war with binary instead of form-data.thanks Gas

Comment: Gas, as u mentioned facing difficulty to redeploy updated war file , facing issue raised at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66160529/liberty-redeploy-fail-with-mbean?noredirect=1#comment117067358_66160529